# Is the Javascript String length constant time?

Tags: javascript, string, performance

I'm fairly new to JS, and realize length is considered a property. But I received a comment to not use str.length in a loop:

`for (i=0; i<str.length; i++){...}`

vs

```
var len = str.length;
for (i=0; i<len; i++){...}
```

Now, I know str.length() is constant time operation in Java because length is stored as a field in String class. But then again, strings are immutable in Java.
I am not sure about JS strings though. Is str.length guaranteed constant time in JS too? Couldn't find this discussed anywhere in the web.

Comment: As far as I know strings are immutable in javascripts aswell and the length instance property is computed just once. I don't know who told you to don't use str.length in a for loop, but I don't think it makes much sense at all, because you are just **accessing** an object property, hence unless that property is a function (which is not the case) that property is not processed, so it shouldn't be really a problem at all. Perhaps he meant something else? (also, by using the len variable you are just referencing the property, so I can't really foresee the difference)

Comment: @briosheje Maybe `w3schools` told him so.. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_performance.asp

Comment: People need to learn to ignore what w3schools says

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim: Nice catch, it seems, indeed, that it is the case. However, as slebetman said, w3school is anything BUT an official source, I would rather believe to such information on MDN or somewhere else, but w3school has just as much impact on my knowledge as yahoo answers does. Just saying :P. In any case, by testing in jsperfs, there **apparently is no difference in terms of performances**, so...

Answer (score 19):

Strings are also immutable in JavaScript. The `length` property does not need to be computed each time it is accessed.

I created a [jsperf benchmark](http://jsperf.com/str-length) for you to view here.

You'll notice the speeds are the same.

Comment: This was not always the case. Performance benchmarks from 10 years ago (before jsperf existed) showed that string.length was O(n). So it has always been "good practice" to cache the length or write loops as `for (var i=0,j=str.length-1;j>=0;i++,j--) ..`. Personally though I'd just use `length` anyway and these days it doesn't matter

Comment: @slebetman: Really? Which engines did compute the length of the string on access?

Comment: @maček The link you shared is not working!

Answer (score 5):

> Is `str.length` guaranteed constant time in JS too?

No, in fact there are no runtime performance or complexity guarantees in JavaScript whatsoever.

However, yes, it can be expected to be accessible in constant time, with no dynamic linear time length computation on access. The ECMAScript spec also describes the [String `.length` property](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-properties-of-string-instances-length) as immutable and that it is initialised when the string is constructed.

Answer (score 2):

In any language that has immulate strings, whether Java, JavaScript, C# or others, it will be a very bad practice by the creators of the language NOT to provide a "constant time" "length" operation for a string. 
Since the string is immutable, its length cannot change, hence all it is required is to store the length of the string upon creation in some field inside the string object and return it upon calling to the "length" propery/method.

Answer (score 0):

Length is an instance property and it's constant time

> It must be implement a string with a given length that is represented as a contiguous, zero-terminated array of jschars. It does this by explicitly storing a length and a pointer to the zero-terminated array

Explicitly stored is the indicator here that it's constant time.

Read [How Strings Are Implemented In SpiderMonkey](https://blog.mozilla.org/ejpbruel/2012/02/06/how-strings-are-implemented-in-spidermonkey-2/)
for more info on how Firefox implements strings.

Comment: "*the length of the string is stored null terminated*" doesn't really make any sense. Nice article you dug up, though!

Comment: @Bergi you're right, I updated my language to be correct! I was thinking of a bstr.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to have been well answered, but here's another 2¢ which may be helpful.

Using `string.length` can cause unexpected behavior in for loops if the string is overwritten by something with a different length inside the loop  e.g:

```
var k = "abcabcabc";
for(var i=0; i<k.length; i++){
  k=k.slice(0,-1);
  console.log(k);
}
```

Will log "abcabcab", "abcabca", ... , "abca" and then stop because the length is changing.

Of course, this may be intentional, in which case go for it (although arguably you should use a while loop).

Comment: In fact, the immutable string doesn't change its length, but you overwrite `k` with a different string.