# what is the time complexity of the Array.prototype.length method in javascript?

Tags: arrays, methods, time, prototype, complexity-theory

I've searched on MDN and w3schools, they don't provide infos on time complexity

as well as stack overflow 
[Javascript: Is the length method efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592241/javascript-is-the-length-method-efficient) & 
[Is the Javascript String length constant time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926007/is-the-javascript-string-length-constant-time)

but none stated whether the length the method kept the size of the array every time it got modified, or it has to be calculated every time it's called.

Comment: This may be implementation-dependent. I seem to remember many years back that Mozilla's JS implementation generated different code based on the types of objects involved in hot code, so the answer might be "linear, until the code is used enough to drop it to a constant."