# When to determine a value once and store it in a variable, rather then determine it repeatedly, (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, performance

So, I'm doing some string manipulations in javascript. Does it makes any difference in terms of execution speed or memory use, if I use s.length (, t.length, u.length,..) repeatedly in my code, or rather I assign these to variables (sLen = s.length..) once? If at all, the impact might be little, but I'm talking heavy loads server-side, which might have an effect on overall performance.

Comment: Micro-optimizations like that are only worth worrying about for extreme performance situations.

Comment: @Pointy, I am aware this is microoptimizing, and probably wouldn't ask otherwise, but this is about a) learning to do frequent coding the best way possible, for good b) parts of code running over and over server-side, so it might translate into some performance impact after all.
Also, part of my question is about other datatypes (or scenarios), where deciding to go with vars (or not), would not be concidered micro-optimizing anymore.

Comment: [string.length is constant time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30926018/11168593)

Comment: JavaScript runtimes are *highly* optimized for object property lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific situation of string length, you can find very detailed answers on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926007/is-the-javascript-string-length-constant-time).

However as a general rule, accessing an object property is one of the fastest operations available to you, more or less equivalent to accessing a local variable. Obviously if it is a "deep" property, ie `object.child.value.field.thing`, it will be slightly faster to set it to a local variable, but I cannot imagine a situation where that would have a noticeable impact on performance.

An exception to this are [Javascript getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). Since these are an internal implementation detail, you may not know when they are being used.

In short: accessing object properties *probably* won't have any impact on your performance - however, a poorly designed object with an inefficient getter may have an impact.

---

Personally, I wouldn't worry about these distinctions while coding and only dig into performance when there is a proven problem (measuring that is beyond the scope of this question).